# Format date time using ToString and convert back to date time C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date time to a specific format using a CultureInfo object and ToString

for example:

```
var dateTime = someDate.ToString(cultureInfoObject);
```

The problem is that dateTime is a string after this executes but I still need it to be a DateTime object.  If I try to convert it back to a DateTime I get an exception because it is in a different format (specifically en-AU in this case).  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: "but I still need it to be a DateTime object" -- then use `someDate`...

Comment: If you need a `DateTime`, why are you converting it to a string in the first place?

Comment: someDate isn't formatted...the only reason I'm converting it to a string is so that it is formatted to the locale

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the Date type. The date is not related to any specific format, it represents a point in time. Just when you need a string representation of it, you would be concerned about the format and culture.

Comment: Oh. Come on you have both string datetime and the original someDate. What is the problem

Comment: What does `DateTime.Parse(dateTime);` get you?

Comment: i see what you mean...that makes sense @gustavodidomenico

Answer (score 3):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-au");
var dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(cultureInfo);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateTime, cultureInfo);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some description apart from the snippet.

Comment: Clear and concise.

Comment: Any way to do something similar for `Xamarin.Essentials.Location` instead of `DateTime`? I'd like to store Location to SQLite database, but the object type is not supported. Storing it is simple with `.ToString()`, but using later causes issues.

Comment: @s3c - This is an entirely different question. You should consider making a new post to get  the widest exposure.

Answer (score 0):

To convert back from string to DateTime, use the DateTime.parse method

For example (assuming dateTime is your string):

```
DateTime dteParsed = DateTime.Parse(dateTime, cultureInfoObject);
```

Note, this is a static method Optionally you can add a third parameter, Which is a DateTimeStyles Enumeration, which permits you to "guide" the parser for which format the date's text is presented see (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)